# Late edits by question askers removes the original content - needs to be added to a review queue

Tags: feature-request, review, edits

In some rare cases a user will edit their question weeks or months after posting it to remove the original content of their post, maybe for legal or other reasons.

Two examples:

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/17783104/revisions

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/33550130/revisions

The user has the ability to flag it to be deleted but not so sure that guarantees that it is deleted.

My suggestions are:

If a late edit is made where a significant portion of the content and/or title is modified then it should be reviewed or perhaps simply flagged for deletion to honor that user's intent.

I can't see all the review queues but I do not believe this is already occurring based on the timing of the changes in the revision history.

Comment: Rolled back :)  Aside, I'm pretty sure that moderators get an auto-flag in these sorts of situations describing the behaviour (e.g. Defacing, edit wars... etc). Also, *The user has the ability to flag it to be deleted but not so sure that guarantees that it is deleted.* Then why add a review queue? You can guarantee that a moderator has made a decision regarding a flag. If it isn't deleted, they *could* ask to be disassociated from the post as well, as a last resort.

Comment: Based on the timing of the changes and the rollbacks, it does not look like they were reviewed/auto-flagged at all - I could be wrong on this.. perhaps review queue is maybe not the most appropriate suggestion then.

Comment: Well, if you see something like that, then rollback. The queue is kind of pointless: no action would arise, and moderators would be informed if any problems ensues. Maybe I'm wrong about auto-flags for unnoticed , destroyed posts, but I know that there are auto-flags for certain situations... There's a post on meta.so somewhere...

Comment: Ah... Here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306821/4293417

Comment: I see.. only auto flagged if *multiple* posts are defaced which explains why the posts I linked were not auto flagged since they were isolated instances of a user doing this.

Comment: In those cases, it's probably worth raising a flag since you can't really rollback sometimes, and chances are, there may be other issues on other questions as well. (I think I rejected your edit when rolling back, sorry :/)

Comment: It's okay, I had an actual edit rather then just rolling back since I didn't know you could rollback to a specific revision.

Comment: Yep, that's something with the edits privileges. :)